# Optional chaining in combination with toLowerCase and indexOf during array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, indexof, optional-chaining

For a autocomplete input I search in project properties during typing. Now I want to improve this code

```js
filterProjects(value: string) {
  return this.projects.filter(
    project =>
      project.key.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase().trim()) >=
        0 ||
      project.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase().trim()) >=
        0 ||
      project.description?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase().trim()) >=
        0
  );
}
```

with this:

```js
filterProjects(value: string) {
  return this.projects.filter(project =>
    [project.key, project.name, project.description].map(
      str => str?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase().trim()) >= 0
    )
  );
}
```

I use the optional chaining because `description` can be null or undefined.

But it doesn't work, meaning the function always returns the array unmodified. Also, when the value is found in the description of one item, the array doesn't get filtered to only this item.

What could be the solution except using "old" checks like `if (str !== undefined)` and such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `map` returns an array of booleans, which is always truthy no matter what, so it's not the predicate you are looking for. You need [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (also in lodash/underscore/ramda, if you plan to target old browsers). Let me tweak also the inner predicate a little bit:

```
filterProjects(value: string) {
  return this.projects.filter(project =>
    [project.key, project.name, project.description].some(str =>
      str ? str.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase().trim()) : false
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Neat, works! But I'm still thinking of a way to get rid of the ternary operator ...

Comment: What @sivako proposes - `(str ?? "")` or `(str || "")  - is also a valid and quite typical approach.

Comment: @JeanD, With this Nice fix of using `some`, you can try with optional chaining `(str) => str?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value?.toLowerCase().trim()) >= 0`  (or `str => (str ?? "").toLowerCase().indexOf((value ?? "").toLowerCase().trim()) >= 0`

Comment: @sivako Great, this works perfect now and is my preferred solution:
`str => str?.toLowerCase().indexOf(value?.toLowerCase().trim()) >= 0`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Nullish coalescing operator (??)'

like

```
str => (str ?? "").toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase().trim()) >= 0
```

Comment: This still returns `false` always.

Comment: JeanD see my above comment, my bad, this fix alone will not work. @tokland has the complete fix.